# if else elif always yields incorrect value

Tags: python

my if,elif,else statement always yields else even if the if is true.

```
value = input("Please enter a product code.")

if value == 34512340:
    #code
elif value == 98981236:
    #code
else:
     print("Product not found")
```

When I input 34512340 I get "Product not found"

Comment: You need to cast your value to `int`

Comment: Put the values in quotes:
if value == "34512340":

Answer (score 0):

Python always treats `input()` as a string so cast `input()` to int:

```
value = int(input("Please enter a product code."))

if value == 34512340:
    #code
elif value == 98981236:
    #code
else:
     print("Product not found")
```

Comment: since the Input can take non-numeric values, its safer to put the numbers in quotes than to cast the str to int
if value == "34512340":

Comment: I wanted to put that up too but both ways work.

Comment: yep, both are valid answers for this simple example :)

Comment: @Achillies - its better because by casting the str to int you are making the huge assumption that all product codes will always be numeric, and that all users will only ever enter numeric values into a free text input box. anything other than a numeric value will generate a run time error even though the IF statement already has a usable ELSE that could handle bad product codes.

Testing the str input against a str value is far safer than attempting to cast a user entered str to int, and doing integer comparisons. A lot less chance of a runtime error and will handle nonnumeric product codes.

Comment: Hmm, a better practice in this case.And yes,I did assume user would like to store ints judging from the code hence this answer. Thanks for the advice. :)